# jQuery Mobile addClass does not affect styles

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Im using the addClass function with jQuery Mobile. I can see in the code that the class is added but its style that should be applied to it is ignored.

If I add the class to the html and refresh the page then the class is styled. So it seems to me that it might be something to with how JQM renders the page.

```
    $('.slider1').click(function(){
        $('.sliders').addClass('.slidersPosTwo');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check-out the documentation for `.addClass()`: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Notice how the examples omit the period (`.`) at the beginning of the class name. If you leave the period then it will be added as part of the class name, which should only be used as a selector.

Your code will work if you make this change:

```
...
$('.sliders').addClass('slidersPosTwo');//notice, no period before the class name
...
```

Answer (score 1):

After modifying JQM content programmatically you usually need to refresh the enhancement.
This can be done for instance with `$(".slider").slider("refresh");`.
Additionally, enhanced elements have a radically different structure after enhancement (many new DOM elements are added for a single slider for instance). it might be the case that you are not adding your class to the proper DOM element (cannot verify this unless you set up a jsfiddle or similar).

Comment: JQM isnt enhancing .slider1 or . slider1, there just divs I gave those classes to. Ill try the "refresh" when im back at work tomorrow but I dont think this is the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

```
    $('.sliders').addClass('.slidersPosTwo');
```

with:

```
    $('.sliders').addClass('slidersPosTwo');
```

Even better, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/fmJhF/) you can find a live jsFiddle example how to modify every slider element. For example:

```
// Slider label
$('div[data-role="fieldcontain"] label#slider-label').addClass('custom-slider-label');
// Slider text box
$('div[data-role="fieldcontain"] input#slider').addClass('custom-slider');
// Slider element
$('div[data-role="fieldcontain"] div[role="application"]').addClass('custom-slider-element');
// Slider button
$('div[data-role="fieldcontain"] div[role="application"] a span').addClass('custom-slider-button');
```

Comment: Your 'replace:' and 'with:' are the same. Also 'slider1' is just the name of my div. It could also have been 'dsafdsaf', its not a JQM component.

Comment: I have fixed my answer. You had an excess dot in this part of code: ('.slidersPosTwo'), it should be only ('slidersPosTwo'). As this is a class name no need for . (dot class) identificator.